# Tensorflow object detection api installation problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm trying to install the TF Object Detection API following instructions from [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#general-remarks).
Not using anything related to GPU.
I successfully have already gone through everything except this line:
`python -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver .`
after computing that command I get:

```
(Py37_{defect_detector}) MacBook-Pro-melamoro:research melamoro$ python -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver .

Usage:   
  /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/bin/python -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/bin/python -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/bin/python -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/bin/python -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/bin/python -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

option --use-feature: invalid choice: '2020-resolver' (choose from 'fast-deps', 'truststore', 'no-binary-enable-wheel-cache')
```

I am not an expert in python and I have no idea what else should I check or install to solve this error.
I tried to google it but haven't met anything what might help yet.
any help will be very welcome.

my laptop: MacBook Pro late 2014, macOS Big Sur 11.7.
I created a virtual environment for my task and I am doing the other commands already there.
Having my venv active I checked whether main packages installed:

```
(Py37_{defect_detector}) MacBook-Pro-melamoro:research melamoro$ pip --version
pip 23.0.1 from /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
(Py37_{defect_detector}) MacBook-Pro-melamoro:research melamoro$ pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.12.0rc0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: absl-py, astunparse, flatbuffers, gast, google-pasta, grpcio, h5py, jax, keras, libclang, numpy, opt-einsum, packaging, protobuf, setuptools, six, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, termcolor, typing-extensions, wrapt
Required-by: 
(Py37_{defect_detector}) MacBook-Pro-melamoro:research melamoro$ python --version
Python 3.11.2
```

---

An UPDATE

I took into account some advices from the answers and looks like thing got better but still there is an error, but a bit different:

```
(Py37_{defect_detector}) MacBook-Pro-melamoro:research melamoro$ python -m pip install .
Processing /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/models/research
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting avro-python3
  Downloading avro-python3-1.10.2.tar.gz (38 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting apache-beam
  Downloading apache-beam-2.45.0.zip (3.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.0/3.0 MB 3.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (9.4.0)
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.9.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (0.29.33)
Requirement already satisfied: contextlib2 in /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (21.6.0)
Collecting tf-slim
  Downloading tf_slim-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (352 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 352.1/352.1 kB 7.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (1.16.0)
Collecting pycocotools
  Downloading pycocotools-2.0.6.tar.gz (24 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting lvis
  Downloading lvis-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (1.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (1.5.3)
Collecting tf-models-official>=2.5.1
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.3/2.3 MB 3.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorflow_io
  Downloading tensorflow_io-0.31.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl (24.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 24.6/24.6 MB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: keras in /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (2.12.0rc1)
Collecting pyparsing==2.4.7
  Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 67.8/67.8 kB 5.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting sacrebleu<=2.2.0
  Downloading sacrebleu-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (116 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 116.6/116.6 kB 10.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting portalocker
  Downloading portalocker-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting regex
  Downloading regex-2022.10.31-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (293 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 294.0/294.0 kB 11.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tabulate>=0.8.9
  Downloading tabulate-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17 in /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from sacrebleu<=2.2.0->object-detection==0.1) (1.23.5)
Collecting colorama
  Downloading colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting gin-config
  Downloading gin_config-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.3/61.3 kB 6.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting google-api-python-client>=1.6.7
  Downloading google_api_python_client-2.80.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 11.0/11.0 MB 24.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting immutabledict
  Downloading immutabledict-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (4.0 kB)
Collecting kaggle>=1.3.9
  Downloading kaggle-1.5.13.tar.gz (63 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 63.3/63.3 kB 5.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting oauth2client
  Downloading oauth2client-4.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 98.2/98.2 kB 9.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting opencv-python-headless
  Downloading opencv_python_headless-4.7.0.72-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_16_x86_64.whl (53.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 53.9/53.9 MB 15.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5.4.3 in /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (5.9.4)
Collecting py-cpuinfo>=3.3.0
  Downloading py_cpuinfo-9.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting pyyaml<6.0,>=5.1
  Downloading PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 175.1/175.1 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting sentencepiece
  Downloading sentencepiece-0.1.97.tar.gz (524 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 524.7/524.7 kB 18.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting seqeval
  Downloading seqeval-1.2.2.tar.gz (43 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 43.6/43.6 kB 4.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting tf-models-official>=2.5.1
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.3/2.3 MB 21.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.3/2.3 MB 8.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.2/2.2 MB 22.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.2/2.2 MB 3.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 3.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 3.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.0/2.0 MB 7.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.2/2.2 MB 3.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.8/1.8 MB 18.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.1 in /Users/melamoro/Desktop/venvs/Py37_{defect_detector}/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (6.0)
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.8/1.8 MB 6.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.8/1.8 MB 5.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.8/1.8 MB 4.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.8/1.8 MB 1.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.6/1.6 MB 4.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of sacrebleu to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting sacrebleu<=2.2.0
  Downloading sacrebleu-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (92 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 92.0/92.0 kB 2.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyparsing to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of object-detection to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Cannot install object-detection and object-detection==0.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    tf-models-official 2.11.3 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.11.2 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.11.0 depends on opencv-python-headless==4.5.2.52
    object-detection 0.1 depends on sacrebleu<=2.2.0
    tf-models-official 2.10.1 depends on sacrebleu==2.2.0
    tf-models-official 2.10.0 depends on opencv-python-headless==4.5.2.52
    tf-models-official 2.9.2 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.9.1 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.9.0 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.8.0 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.7.2 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.7.1 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.7.0 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.6.1 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.6.0 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.5.1 depends on tensorflow-addons

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

Comment: Just remove the --use-feature=2020-resolver parameter, it should work without it, the documentation you are using is a bit outdated.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I tried to call "python -m pip install", but I got: "ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
".

Comment: you forgot the . at the end of the command

Comment: I tried to do so but I got : "ERROR: unknown command "install." - maybe you meant "install""

Comment: Come on, directly in your example, there is a space between install and the period, I only said to remove one parameter.

Comment: Yes, it worked, but I got the new error...:( :)

Look at the updated version of my question above. 
To speak shorted the error is: 
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of object-detection to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Cannot install object-detection and object-detection==0.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.